# Which tense is used in conditionals which refer to the past?

Tags: conditionals

> If I had food at home, I would not have come here.

In the former clause of this sentence, should  past perfect(If I had had food at home) not be used instead of simple past, as the event being talked about refers to the past ?

Comment: Past perfect is correct.

Comment: [in the previous clause or clause above] Yes, If I had had is right.

Comment: (Upvoted Lambie's comment in error). I

Comment: Simple past is correct if the speaker means "RIGHT NOW I have no food at home, and if I did have food at home, I would not have come."

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the speaker has come here today or is referring to an earlier occasion.

> If I had food at home [now] I would not have come here [today].
>
> If I had had food at home [then], I would not have come here [on that occasion].

Comment: The second example also works for "this occasion" or "today."  A past condition can be linked to a present outcome.  The question is whether the food at home refers to the present or the past, not when you come given the sentence at issue.

Comment: If the latter part of the sentence refers to the present, shouldn't the sentence be used with 'would' instead of 'would have', as 'would have' is used in when referring to the past ?

Comment: If the speaker is 'here', the action of 'coming here' is already in the (recent) past.

Comment: So, 'would' should be used, right ?

Comment: _Would_ should be used for what? I provided two examples (for different circumstances) in my answer.